# Why is the browser showing the blank page?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run the code in a browser and after `"Enter any String"` command, it just shows the blank page.

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang = "en">
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>PracticeCoding</title>
    <script language = "Javascript" src = "FirstReverse.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script language = "Javascript" type = "text/javascript">
    var myString = prompt("Please enter any String");
        document.write("The reverse of the " + myString + " is " + reverseString(myString));

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

FirstReverse.js File:

```
function reverseString(myString){
    var reverseString = "";
    for(var i = myString.length; i > 0; i--){
        reverseString += myString[i];
    }
    return reverseString;
}
```

Comment: Then post your answer. It might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the *document.write* clause. When you execute it a new page is opened (because is intended to do so, to create a new document with your stream).

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score -1):

Because your method **reverseString** is not defined when your code is being executed. Consider putting your code in the onLoad event or use jQuery domready event.